# Angular (ui-router) Routing not fully working? Can't directly access to url w/o going through base url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Hello to everyone thanks in advance for your help,

I am having tough time trying to figure out why my routing is not fully working.  I am going to explain.

I do have a nav bar with dropdown options which leads to the routes I've defined on my angular app config stage.

HTML

```
<head>
...
<base href="/">
...
</head>
...
(inside navbar)
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a ui-sref="Check">Check</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

JS (config)

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


$stateProvider

// HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html'
});

// SERVICE VIEWS =================================

$stateProvider
    .state('Check', {
        url: '/Check',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/Check/Check.html',
        controller: 'CheckCtrl'
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

}]);

Everything runs great when I do access through the home (through index.html -> click on the navbar and access Check) It loads the template properly. 
But when I am trying to access directly to that view nothing gets loaded at all. Blank screen.

To sum up:
Action:
Access localhost:8080 -> All runs OK
Access localhost:8080/Check directly -> Not a single thing is loaded.

No idead what I am missing here.

Thanks for your time and support.

Comment: does http://localhost:8080/#/check works ?

Comment: Yes it works! I tried to remove # because I  do not want to use it but it seems that without it, it can not find the route or something? Do you know how I can fix this?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your server.js file ?

I think you lack some line which should look like this :

```
app.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + "/app"));
```

Comment: If I use what @Ummaheswaran it works but I do not know how to fix it and avoid the use of # on the url. Any tip? Thanks anyway for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

From the frequently asked questions on their wiki:

> How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode
>
> When I add $locationProvider.html5Mode(true), my site will not allow pasting of urls. How do I configure my server to work when html5Mode is true?
>
> When you have html5Mode enabled, the # character will no longer be used in your urls. The # symbol is useful because it requires no server side configuration. Without #, the url looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

How to do that depends on the type of server you are running, it's all explained in the article linked above.